# cant retrieve data to editor AjaxControlToolkit C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i use asp.net 4.5 and i create Project to post news with use ajax
AjaxControlToolkit NET45

data when post is no any problem's and save is success to database ?

data when retrieve to label no problems ? but when i want retrieve to editor box cant show and retrieve empty ? why ? i want update my news by retrieve new to editor box ?

show file.aspx

[image]

i want set retrieve data to editor content ? to update them to database ?

when i post editor.content= " example  any string "; in Page_Load Function is post and no problem ? but when data post to content into file.aspx is post empty ?

why

sea data

[image]

all field is post data from database but content my news cant post into editor i use post my content new into label is success and you can show data content ?

Comment: Show your work as a text, not as an image..

Comment: how to retrieve content_text into editor box ?